# Chaning root of url load to javascript file?

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, loading, document-root

So normally when loading scripts or images into an .html file it uses its current location as the root of the url call functions. Now when loading in an external Javascript file like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="external_java.js"></script>
```

Anything that gets called from the javascript file above will use the .html's location on the server rather than the .js file's location. Is there any way to change this?

That way when I am calling on a XML file it will use the .js location as the root of the call?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: ../template/file.xml,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        /*do something here*/
           }
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look up the absolute src of your script files by looking in `document.scripts`:

So if you know that the first script that you load on the page is `src="external_java.js"`, then checking `document.scripts[0].src` will give you the absolute path to that file.

From there I'd just replace the file name with nothing in the got src and you have an absolute root path... eg:

```
var root = document.scripts[0].src.replace("external_java.js", "");
```

And from there you can append/prepend it to the paths you're trying to call.

Comment: so then when I want to call the new url would I incorporate the root?
`url: root+'template/file.xml',`

Comment: Yeah, instead of `$.ajax({ url: "../template/file.xml" })` you could use `$.ajax({ url: root + "/file.xml" })` - if the files are in your js folder for example